# Cast from "UITableViewCell" to unrelated type "UIView" always fails iOS9

Tags: ios, swift, casting, ios9

After updating to iOS9 I started seeing a weird warning in following code:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
{
    var result: UIView?

    if UserPerspective.List == currentUser.perspective.value
    {
        result = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomHeader") as? UIView
    }

    return result
}
```

And as stated in the heading I get following warning:

> Cast from "UITableViewCell" to unrelated type "UIView" always fails

I can't understand why it fails, as UITableViewCell is a subclass of UIView, then the cast should be fine. However swift compiler doesn't think so :)

Comment: I suppose it is not necessary to cast UIView subclass to UIView.

Comment: You're trying to cast from UITableViewCell? to UIView, and that indeed will always fail. You could cast to UIView? - then it would always succeed. So the best option is not to cast at all - and everything will work as you expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't cast it.

This should be enough

```
let result = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomHeader")
```

where result is `UITableViewCell?`

If you have a custom UITableViewCell, let's call it `customTableViewCell`, you can do the following:

```
let result = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomHeader") as! customTableViewCell
```

Comment: Yep I was trying to upcast - do you ever feel stupid as I do right now :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to cast UITableViewCell to UIView as it will always succeed, you'r getting the above error because you're casting an optional to UIView

```
result = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomHeader")! as? UIView
```

This will work but, there is no use in casting it.

Comment: This way I'll get another error that cast will always succeeds. See @William's answer which is correct.

Comment: yeah, I mentioned that above. it will always succeed so you don't need the casting